# What's the right way to dynamically give height to a UIScrollView depending on the content within?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Here my dilemma. I have 4 elements inside a UIScrollView.
1. Top most element is a UILabel that I give height dynamically depending upon the amount of content in it.
2. Second is a fixed height UILabel that I give position dynamically depending upon the height given to the upper UILabel
3. Third element is a UIImageView that again I have to give position dynamically depending upon the height given to the topmost UILabel
4. The fourth is a UIWebView, to which I gave both, height & position dynamically. (Height depending upon the content in it.. and position again depending on the height of topmost UILabel)

Finally, I dynamically give height to my UIScrollView to accomodate all of the above elements.

Here is the code I use in - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView to accomplish all of the above.

```
//Adjust height of top-most UILabel
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [item.label1 sizeWithFont:label1.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label1.lineBreakMode];
CGRect newFrame = label1.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 0;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
label1.frame = newFrame;

//Adjust position of second UILlabel
CGRect labelPosition = label2.frame;
labelPosition.size.height = 20;
labelPosition.origin.y = expectedLabelSize.height +14;
label2.frame = labelPosition;

//Add UIImageView and adjust it's position
UIImageView *image;
image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, expectedLabelSize.height +41, 320, 2)];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:image];
[image release];

//Adjust UIWebView height and position
CGRect frame = webView.frame;
frame.size.height = 0;
frame.origin.y = expectedLabelSize.height +48;
webView.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
webView.frame = frame;

//Adjust Scrollview height
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, fittingSize.height +expectedLabelSize.height +48);
```

Finally, my problem is that when I first load this view, everything but the scrollview get's proper height & position. But, if I go back one view & open this view again, the scrollview has the desired height.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the scrollView variable isn't yet initialized when this first runs. Try setting a breakpoint somewhere in this code and checking if scrollView has a value or if it's just 0x00000000.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't it, scrollview is indeed getting initialized.